# Drop down Menu Disappears when Selecting by Hovering over submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I hover around  submenu , then when dragging cursor over submenu and hovering over the submenu disappers and only sometimes appear when I  select any other nav menu and hover there but it only works sometimes.

Here is my code

```css
html
{ height: 100%;}

*
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}
body
{ font: normal .80em 'trebuchet ms', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #555;}

p
{ padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;}

#menubar
{ width: 880px;
  height: 46px;} 

ul#menu
{ float: right;
  margin: 0;}

ul#menu li
{ float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
  background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 0 0;}

ul#menu li a
{ font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 100% 0;} 

ul#menu li.selected a
{ height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;}

ul#menu li.selected
{ margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
  background: #00C6F0 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 0 0;}

ul#menu li.selected a, ul#menu li.selected a:hover
{ background: #00C6F0 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
  color: #FFF;}

ul#menu li a:hover
{ color: #E4EC04;}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

      <div id="menubar">
        <ul id="menu"  >


          <li ><a  href="#" >Home</a></li>

    
          <li ><a ref="#" >Contact Us</a></li>
          <li >
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can I solve this ..
Ay help is  appreciated. I tried but I failed and Have no  idea how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is simply a gap between `li.dropdown` and `.dropdown-content`. It is worth noting that when you move the cursor **quickly** from the dropdown button to the dropdown list, it does not disappear. However, doing that slowly vanishes the list.

The simplest solution I could think of here is to decrease the top margin of the dropdown list, while adding a top padding to the first list item to compensate for that lost margin (a top margin won't work here). So, your code for the dropdown menu would look like this:

```css
#menubar {
  width: 880px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul#menu {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}

ul#menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
  background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
}

ul#menu li.selected a {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
}

ul#menu li.selected {
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
  background: #00C6F0 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

ul#menu li.selected a,
ul#menu li.selected a:hover {
  background: #00C6F0 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
  color: #FFF;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
  color: #E4EC04;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:first-child {
  padding-top:17px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a ref="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because there is a space between the "Dropdown" menu and the dropdown list. Instead of hard coding the margin in px use a percentage. I also recommend using top instead of margin-top. Replace .dropdown-content css with:

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100%; //To move it up or down more you can use calc like: calc(100% + 1px) or calc(100% - 2px)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you move the mouse from the dropdown menu toggle, into the submenu, you are briefly not hovering over the div due to the margin-top value of the submenu. If you really want that divide between the two add white top border (i.e. border-top: 2px solid white;).

Heres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojtramp/p3hqs652/)

Change the CSS as follows:

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Change the HTML as follows:

```
<li class="dropdown"> 
  <div>
   <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <a href="#">Link 2</a>
       <a href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</li>
```